# How to solve this type of recursive formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I know how to solve recursive formulas when the `T(n)` term is a whole number. However, when it isn't, I have no idea what to do. Can someone explain this to me with regards to solving this problem?

```
    Solve the following recursive formula.
    Try to find the exact solution. If you cannot use, Big Oh, Omega or Theta notations.

 n>=1 is a power of 2 integer.
 T(1)=0
 T(n)=2T(n/2)+n
```

I have tried the following thus far.

I know that

```
T(2) = 2T(1) + 2 =2 
T(4) = 2T(2) + 4 =8
```

However, I don't know what to do about

```
T(3) = 2T(3/2) + 3
```

I don't understand how you can have a 1.5th term `T(3/2)`. Can someone please help me to understand and solve this? Thanks

Comment: $n$ is a power of $2$. Try $n = 2^k$ for some $k$.

Comment: Does that mean substituting 2^k for n in the whole problem?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\mrm{T}\pars{1} = 0\,,\quad
> \mrm{T}\pars{n} = 2\,\mrm{T}\pars{n/2} + n:\ ?\,;\qquad n \equiv 2^{\ell}\,,\ \ell \geq 0.\quad\mbox{Note that}\ \ell = \ln\pars{n}/\ln\pars{2}}$.

\begin{align}
\mrm{T}\pars{n} = 2\,\mrm{T}\pars{n \over 2} + n \implies
{\mrm{T}\pars{n} \over n} & =
{\mrm{T}\pars{n/2} \over n/2} + 1 =
{\mrm{T}\pars{n/2^{2}} \over n/2^{2}} + 2 =
{\mrm{T}\pars{n/2^{3}} \over n/2^{3}} + 3
\\[5mm] & = \cdots =
{\mrm{T}\pars{n/2^{\ell}} \over n/2^{\ell}} + \ell\ =\
\overbrace{\mrm{T}\pars{1}}^{\ds{=\ 0}}\ +\ \ell =
{\ln\pars{n} \over \ln\pars{2}}
\\[5mm] &\implies\quad
\bbox[8px,border:0.1em groove navy]{\mrm{T}\pars{n} =
{n\ln\pars{n} \over \ln\pars{2}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

we get $$T(n)=T \left( 1 \right) n+{\frac {n\ln  \left( n \right) }{\ln  \left( 2
 \right) }}
$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance, but can you please explain the steps for how you end up with the logarithm?

Comment: Also note that $T(1)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

This recursion is of the form $T(n) = aT\left(\frac nb\right) + f(n)$ where $f(n)\in\Theta\left(n^{\log_b a} \log^0 n \right)$, so by the master theorem, we have $T(n)\in\Theta(n\log n)$. When $n=2^k$, $k=0,1,2,\ldots$ we may verify by induction that this is an exact solution to the recurrence. That is, $T\left(2^k\right) = k2^k$ for $k\geqslant 0$. The base case $k=0$ is trivial, as $$0 = T\left(2^0\right) = 0\cdot 2^0. $$
Assume that $T\left(2^k\right)=k2^k$ for some nonnegative integer $k$. Then
\begin{align}
T\left(2^{k+1}\right) &= 2T\left(2^k\right) + 2^{k+1}\\
&= 2\left(k2^k\right) + 2^{k+1}\\
&= (k+1)2^{k+1},
\end{align}
from which we conclude.